# ¿Porque mi formulario tipo submit no reconoce los required, aun teniendo el button com type="submit"? (Angular) esto pasa en mi proyecto nada mas

Tags: html, css, angular

```html
<form action="" method="POST" id="form">
    <div class="form">
      <h1>Tus Datos</h1>
      <div class="grupo">
        <input type="text" name="" id="first-name" value="" required/><span
          class="barra"
        ></span>
        <label for="">Nombre</label>
      </div>
      <div class="grupo">
        <input type="text" name="" id="last-name" required /><span
          class="barra"
        ></span>
        <label for="">Apellidos</label>
      </div>
      <div class="grupo">
        <input type="number" name="" id="identification" required /><span
          class="barra"
        ></span>
        <label for="">Identificación</label>
      </div>
      <div class="grupo">
        <input type="email" name="" id="email" required /><span
          class="barra"
        ></span>
        <label for="">Correo Electronico</label>
      </div>
      <div class="grupo">
        <input type="text" name="" id="depto" required /><span
          class="barra"
        ></span>
        <label for="">Departamento</label>
      </div>
      <div class="grupo">
        <input type="text" name="" id="city" required /><span
          class="barra"
        ></span>
        <label for="">Ciudad</label>
      </div>
      <div class="grupo">
        <input type="number" name="" id="phone" required /><span
          class="barra"
        ></span>
        <label for="">Celular</label>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" (click)="enviarDatos()">Enviar</button>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Este es mi formulario, intente crear un formulario en otra parte bien sencillo y también pasa lo mismo.

El problema es que el button esta como type="submit" y no esta agarrando, no se la razon, ya intente de todo pero pasa con cualquier formulario que añada al proyecto :(

Ahora ejectando el codigo aqui insertado, veo que funciona normal, pero en mi proyecto no me agarra los required

Comment: Títutlo = idea general. Cuerpo del mensaje = detalles.

Comment: He probado tu código y sí funciona. Deberías subir todo el código no solamente el formulario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seguramente te está pasando esto: https://angular.io/api/forms/NgForm#native-dom-validation-ui

> In order to prevent the native DOM form validation UI from interfering
> with Angular's form validation, Angular automatically adds the
> novalidate attribute on any  whenever FormModule or
> ReactiveFormModule are imported into the application.

Y una posible solución es la que dicen a continuación:

> If you want to explicitly enable native DOM validation UI with Angular
> forms, you can add the ngNativeValidate attribute to the 
> element:

```
<form ngNativeValidate>
```

Comment: No veo que esté usando ReactiveForms ni siquiera los Form del FormModule de angular. Otra cosa que puede estar pasando, y creo que puede ser el problema porque su action está vacío (""), es que en la función bindeada `enviarDatos()` está haciendo el envío del formulario a través de http directamente...  y ese click se va a ejecutar igual aunque el formulario no sea válido, porque es un bind que añade él mismo, no un `submit` *"normal"*. De todas maneras, si no añade el código completo solo podemos elucubrar y no dar una respuesta segura.

Comment: Yo lo he probado en jsfiddle y funcionaba tal cual lo tiene, es decir, la validación se efectuaba igual, y su problema segun dice es que a el no le funciona en su proyecto angular, y que sin yo tener ni la mas remota idea, entiendo que eso se ejecuta de algun modo preprocesando ese html y generando un nuevo html de salida distinto a lo que vemos (fíjate en el (click) ese que no es html puro, por eso lo digo y he investigado sobre el tema encontrando esa problematica con esta solución que acabo de aportar).

Comment: La solución que me compartiste fue la ideal, funciono perfectamente, Muchas gracias. Solo tuve que poner en la etiqueta form el ngNativeValidate

Comment: Perfecto, me alegro :-)